# Enabling anonymous access

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I created a role in ElasticSearch that has the access to /_cluster/health. I specified the role in the ES K8S yaml and my elastic search is not working (unless I remove the config from yaml file).
Did I enable the right configuration in my yaml file?

```
POST: http://{{ES_HOST}}/_security/role/gce_healthcheck_role
{
  "cluster": [ "monitor" ]
}
```

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: xyz
spec:
  version: 8.6.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
      xpack.security.authc:
        anonymous:
          username: _es_anonymous_user
          roles: gce_healthcheck_role
          authz_exception: true
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: LoadBalancer
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Is the elastic search instance not working? config looks good though.

Comment: @glenacota I'm able to access now. Previously after I enabled the config, I got connection refuse. Not sure because of GKE deployment requires some time for the pod to startup back.